Как сделать сервисы согласованными
У меня есть микросервисы (orders и products), иногда продукты заканчиваются (amount = 0) и бывает так, что при создании заказ еще не знает о том, что продукты закончились. В результате заказ становится невалидным. Как мне обеспечить консистентность между сервисами?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Смотрите в сторону transactional outbox, saga и т.п., вот навскидку можно почитать https://habr.com/ru/companies/lamoda/articles/678932/

Много чего можно сделать. Варианты: 1) Перед сохранением заказа в БД, попытаться навесить на него продукты. 2) Перед созданием заказа просто заблокировать продукты для него 3) После создания заказа, если продуктов не достаточно, удалить заказ и БД или навесить какой статус, что мол заказ отменен.
